# Uncaught syntax error in my javascript code

Tags: javascript, identifier

Im getting an "Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected Identifier" error in my javascript code on. This code is basically just a 1 to 1 copy from a tutorial which I adapted to fit to my html file.The error occurs on line 86 within the "Create StickyNote" function.
Here goes the code:

```
(function ($, $S) {
//$ jQuery
//$S window.localStorage
//Variables Declaration
var $board = $('#board'),
    //Board where the stickyNotes are stuck
    stickyNoteClass, //Singleton Object containing the Functions to work with the LocalStorage
    len = 0,
    //Length of Objects in the LocalStorage 
    currentNotes = '',
    //Storage the html construction of the stickyNotes
    o; //Actual stickyNoteClass data in the localStorage



//Manage the stickyNotes in the Local Storage
//Each stickyNote is saved in the localStorage as an Object  
stickyNoteClass = {
    add: function (obj) {
        obj.id = $S.length;
        $S.setItem(obj.id, JSON.stringify(obj));
    },

    retrive: function (id) {
        return JSON.parse($S.getItem(id));
    },

    remove: function (id) {
        $S.removeItem(id);
    },

    removeAll: function () {
        $S.clear();
    }

};

//If any stickyNote exists, Create it/them
len = $S.length;
if (len) {
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        //Create all stickyNotes saved in localStorage
        var key = $S.key(i);
        o = stickyNoteClass.retrive(key);
        currentNotes += '<div class="stickyNote"';
        currentNotes += ' style="left:' + o.left;
        currentNotes += 'px; top:' + o.top;
        //data-key is the attribute to know what item delete in the localStorage
        currentNotes += 'px"><div class="toolbar"><span class="delete" data-key="' + key;
        currentNotes += '">x</span></div><div contenteditable="true" class="editable">';
        currentNotes += o.text;
        currentNotes += '</div></div>';
    }

    //Append all the stickyNotes to the board
    $board.html(currentNotes);
}

/*Dont need to implement this one, as it is already implemented in the html index file
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//When the document is ready, make all stickyNotes Draggable
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".stickyNote").draggable({
        cancel: '.editable',
        "zIndex": 3000,
        "stack" : '.stickyNote'
    });
});*/

//Remove stickyNoteClass
$('span.delete').live('click', function () {
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this Note?')) {
        var $this = $(this);
        //data-key is the attribute to know what item delete in the localStorage
        stickyNote.remove($this.attr('data-key'));
        $this.closest('.stickyNote').fadeOut('slow', function () {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    }
});

//Create stickyNote
$('#new stickyNote').click(function () {
    $board.append('<div class="stickyNote" style="left:20px;top:70px">
            <span class="delete" title="Close">x</span>
            <h1>Drag Me</h1>
            <p class="editable">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum..</p>
</div>');

    /*Dont need to do this, as the draggable is implemented in the html file for all
    divs which are placed within the #board.
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $(".stickyNote").draggable({
        cancel: '.editable'
    });*/
});

//Save all the stickyNotes when the user leaves the page
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    //Clean the localStorage
    stickyNoteClass.removeAll();
    //Then insert each stickyNote into the LocalStorage
    //Saving their position on the page, in order to position them when the page is loaded again
    $('.stickyNote').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        stickyNoteClass.add({
            top: parseInt($this.position().top),
            left: parseInt($this.position().left),
            text: $this.children('.editable').text()
        });
    });
}
})(jQuery, window.localStorage);
```

Comment: i have no idea why the last line is seperate from the rest of the code

Comment: You cannot have strings spanning multiple lines in JavaScript (at least not like that).

Comment: See [How to create multiline strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/how-to-create-multiline-strings).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @FelixKling has pointed out, a multiline string is not allowed the way you have it. Change this:

```
$('#new stickyNote').click(function () {
    $board.append('<div class="stickyNote" style="left:20px;top:70px">
            <span class="delete" title="Close">x</span>
            <h1>Drag Me</h1>
            <p class="editable">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum..</p>
</div>');

    /*Dont need to do this, as the draggable is implemented in the html file for all
    divs which are placed within the #board.
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $(".stickyNote").draggable({
        cancel: '.editable'
    });*/
});
```

to this:

```
    $board.append('<div class="stickyNote" style="left:20px;top:70px">' +
            '<span class="delete" title="Close">x</span>' +
            '<h1>Drag Me</h1>' +
            '<p class="editable">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum..</p>' +
            '</div>');
```

Comment: thanks a lot. what also seems to work, as i just found out, is to delete all the spaces between the end of one tag and the beginning of another tag. dont really know why though

Comment: @TheBaj Because you can't put unescaped line breaks in the mid of a string literal.